# Call Angular2 component function from HTML by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am pretty much new in TypeScript and Angular2. I have a problem when I want to call a component function by clicking on the button in HTML.

If I use `**onclick="locateHotelOnMap()"**` on HTML button element I get this error:

> ReferenceError: locateHotelOnMap is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Can someone help me with this? 
In Angular1, I've called my controller funtions using directive **ng-click**.

How should I do it now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the manual: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call the function like this (click)="componentFunctionName()" See below example.

```
<button (click)="locateHotelOnMap()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2, the events can be called using () around normal javascript handlers like

```
<button (click)="locateHotelOnMap()">Hello World</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. 

Appreciate it. 

Regards,
Dejan